# Automatic indentation with AucTeX within \[...\] environment

Tags: indentation, auctex

AucTex works fine automatically indenting most environments, for example

```
\begin{displaymath}
  \cos x
\end{displaymath}
```

but doesn't indent when I use \[ and \], and automatically takes away any indentation I have done manually. It looks like this

```
\[
\cos x
\]
```

but I want it to look like this

```
\[
  \cos x
\]
```

It seems that AucTeX doesn't recognise \[...\] as a displaymath environment for indentation. I've looked at AucTeX customisation for indentation but there doesn't seem to be a way to add an environment to be indented. As I understand it the user option 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list' is for special exceptions.

Is there any way to get AucTeX to indent between \[ and \] ?

Comment: Is using `equation*` environment in place of `\[...\]` an acceptable workaround?

Comment: Not really. If I can't get it to work I'll keep using \\[..\\] without indentation. I know this is a bit fussy for such a silly little thing, but I would like to know if it is possible to get it to behave as I would like.

Comment: `equation*` is a LOT better, when you are using auctex. Then if you need `align*` instead, you just use `C-u C-c C-e align*` and hit return. You cannot do that for `\[... \]`

Comment: @ daleif I did wonder if there was a reason not to use `\[...\]`. The reason I use it is because it gives a bit more white space around the maths, and I find that helps me to read it more easily. I take your point though and will see how it goes.

Comment: If you use the `amsmath` package, `\[...\]` is just an alias of the `equation*` enviromnment.

Comment: @ giordano Sorry that wasn't clear. I meant white space around maths code in the LaTeX source rather than the typeset document.

Comment: @Tom imo `\[\]` makes the code less readable. `\begin... \end` makes much more obvious block structures in the code. Plus as I said, auctex provide a load of cool features that work on environments (in the `\begin... \end` sence). Trust us, once you get deeper into auctex, you do not want to use this construction. In my personal setup I have a quick macro to turn all of them into equation*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following code to your initialization file and restart Emacs

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (defun LaTeX-indent-calculate (&optional force-type)
       "Return the indentation of a line of LaTeX source.
FORCE-TYPE can be used to force the calculation of an inner or
outer indentation in case of a commented line.  The symbols
'inner and 'outer are recognized."
       (save-excursion
     (LaTeX-back-to-indentation force-type)
     (let ((i 0)
           (list-length (safe-length docTeX-indent-inner-fixed))
           (case-fold-search nil)
           entry
           found)
       (cond ((save-excursion (beginning-of-line) (bobp)) 0)
         ((and (eq major-mode 'doctex-mode)
               fill-prefix
               (TeX-in-line-comment)
               (progn
             (while (and (< i list-length)
                     (not found))
               (setq entry (nth i docTeX-indent-inner-fixed))
               (when (looking-at (nth 0 entry))
                 (setq found t))
               (setq i (1+ i)))
             found))
          (if (nth 2 entry)
              (- (nth 1 entry) (if (integerp comment-padding)
                       comment-padding
                     (length comment-padding)))
            (nth 1 entry)))
         ((looking-at (concat (regexp-quote TeX-esc)
                      "\\(begin\\|end\\){\\("
                      LaTeX-verbatim-regexp
                      "\\)}"))
          ;; \end{verbatim} must be flush left, otherwise an unwanted
          ;; empty line appears in LaTeX's output.
          0)
         ((and LaTeX-indent-environment-check
               ;; Special environments.
               (let ((entry (assoc (or LaTeX-current-environment
                           (LaTeX-current-environment))
                       LaTeX-indent-environment-list)))
             (and entry
                  (nth 1 entry)
                  (funcall (nth 1 entry))))))
         ((looking-at (concat (regexp-quote TeX-esc)
                      "\\("
                      LaTeX-end-regexp
                      "\\)"))
          ;; Backindent at \end.
          (- (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type) LaTeX-indent-level))
         ((looking-at (concat (regexp-quote TeX-esc) "right\\b"))
          ;; Backindent at \right.
          (- (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type)
             LaTeX-left-right-indent-level))
         ((looking-at (concat (regexp-quote TeX-esc)
                      "\\("
                      LaTeX-item-regexp
                      "\\)"))
          ;; Items.
          (+ (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type) LaTeX-item-indent))
         ((looking-at "}")
          ;; End brace in the start of the line.
          (- (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type)
             TeX-brace-indent-level))
         ((and (texmathp)
               ;; Display math \[...\], treat as a generic environment.
               (equal "\\[" (car texmathp-why)))
          LaTeX-indent-level)
         (t (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type))))))
     ;; Treat \] as a generic \end{...}
     (setq LaTeX-end-regexp "end\\b\\|\\]")))
```

This redefines `LaTeX-indent-calculate` to cater for `\[...\]` math mode.  Not tested thoroughly, may need some fix.

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked. I'm completely new to emacs and lisp so I have no idea why it worked, but it gives me something to puzzle over. There's no way I would have gotten to this answer on my own any time soon.

Comment: @Tom  Actually I slightly changed the existing `LaTeX-indent-calculate` function to fit your needs, I didn't write that code from the scratch `:-)`  Elisp is pretty easy to know as it is widely documented within Emacs itself, `C-h f`, `C-h v`, `C-h k`, and `C-h i` are your friends `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

Following and using the magnificent answer from @giordano, as base, to a follow up of the question, I made the changes directly in the file `latex.el`, and later configured and compiled AucTeX.

The changes were mostly to try out `\(` instead of `\[`.

```lisp
         ;; Items.
     (+ (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type) LaTeX-item-indent))
    ((looking-at "}")
     ;; End brace in the start of the line.
     (- (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type)
    TeX-brace-indent-level))
    ((and (texmathp)
      ;;Display math \[...\], treat as a generic environment
      (equal "\\[" (car texmathp-why)))
     LaTeX-indent-level)
    ((or (texmathp)
     (equal "\\(" (car texmathp-because)))
     LaTeX-indent-level)
    (t (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type))))))
```

But the above is a mediocre attempt with the current version. `\(` does, what it's supposed to...but that's about it, it's useless.

The following, on the other hand, is less sub par than the above:

```lisp
              ;; Items.
 (+ (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type) LaTeX-item-indent))
((looking-at "}")
 ;; End brace in the start of the line.
 (- (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type)
TeX-brace-indent-level))
((and (texmathp)
  ;;Display math \[...\], treat as a generic environment
  (equal "\\[" (car texmathp-why)))
 LaTeX-left-right-indent-level)
(t (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type))))))
```

Third edit and last: This is what I'm talking about! Shame on me for not seeing it.

Both `\(` and `\[` were compiled with the latest AucTeX.

```
              ;; Items.
 (+ (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type) LaTeX-item-indent))
((looking-at "}")
 ;; End brace in the start of the line.
 (- (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type)
TeX-brace-indent-level))
((and (texmathp)
  ;;Display math \[...\], treat as a generic environment
  (equal "\\[" (car texmathp-why)))
 LaTeX-indent-level)
((and (texmathp)
  (equal "\\(" (car texmathp-why)))
 LaTeX-indent-level)
 (t (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type))))))
```